# convert MATLAB cell type to c++

Tags: c++, matlab, cell, armadillo

i'm converting a MATLAB program in c++ using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#syntax) for matrix algebra.

i'm stuck on [cell](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/21/cell-arrays-and-their-contents/) type. someone has some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Armadillo has [field](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#field) class!

Answer (score 3):

That's because 'cell' is not really a type - it is a placeholder for anything you want to place in it. The closest thing I can think of in languages such as C# and Python is a 'tuple', which intrinsically can contain anonymous types.

Since C++ does not have a built-in tuple type, I suggest you take a look at [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), which is a very comprehensive, mature and open-source library for practically anything you need in C++. Under Boost, take a look at the [Fusion](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/) library, or if you require something not simpler, at the [Tuple](http://www.boost.org/libs/tuple/) library.

**EDIT** as Matt mensioned below, as of TR1, tuples are part of the C++ standard library. See Matt's link [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple).

Comment: Any reason to leave [the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple)?

Comment: @Matt: No, not really. It just slipped my mind the TR1 has tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Your cell data will likely translate fairly well into a C++ object. I would recommend you examine what your cells contain and see if you could represent it as a class. Then you would be able to create vectors/arrays/matrices of your objects and have them treated similar to cells in MATLAB.