# How to use Cell data type of Matlab in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, vector, cell

I want to create a cell (similar to the one used in Matlab) in c++.

```
A = cell (M, 1); % A is {M x 1} cell, each of them is a { N x 2} 
                 % cell like { [key], [value1, value2, ...] }
```

How can i create a cell like A mentioned above in c++?

Comment: `Nx2` is not `[key], [value1, value2, ...]`. It is more like --> `[key] [value]` with N rows are 2 columns.

Comment: I want multiple values for a single key. so i am looking for [key], [value1, value2, ...]

Comment: Possibly related: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9233039/3372061), [2](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/157597-accessing-a-cell-array-of-cell-arrays-in-a-c-mex-file).

Comment: If possible i would like to use just vectors for the same